# Numpy import from CSV and convert columns to float

Tags: python, csv, numpy

ok, so i have a numpy array loaded from a CSV file,
the array looks like :

```
array([['0', '3', '22', ..., '7.25', '1', '0'],
       ['1', '1', '38', ..., '71.2833', '0', '0'],
       ['1', '3', '26', ..., '7.925', '1', '0'],
       ..., 
       ['0', '3', '', ..., '23.45', '1', '0'],
       ['1', '1', '26', ..., '30', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '3', '32', ..., '7.75', '0', '0']], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

I want to convert the array elements to float but i'm having this error

```
data2 = np.array(data).astype(np.float)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

is there a way to solve this problem with numpy or pandas ?

Comment: I think you should look at the root of your problem: how you read in the CSV file. Because this should be able to handle this at once and reading it in as floats. Can you give an extract of how your CSV file looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with a specific value rather than Numpy or your data in general. I think it's the empty string that is causing the problem, there is no way to represent `''` as a float.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is an empty string(`''`) in your array. So, change your array's `''` into `0`s.

Assuming your array is `a`:

```
>>> a[a=='']='0'
>>> a2 = a.astype(np.float)
```